# Best translation for the Egyptian idiom: "He falls standing"

Tags: idiom-requests

When someone is really resilient, to the point that it seems no disaster could destroy them, Egyptians use this idiom, which means that even when they fall, they do not end up flat on the ground; they fall on their feet (just like Batman when he falls from the 100th floor and still somehow ends up on his feet smashing the ground around him).
Is there an idiom in English anywhere close to this meaning?

E.g.:

> "The recession has hit his business hard."
> "Oh don't worry. He is a savvy entrepreneur; he falls standing."

Comment: He's a regular [Chumbawamba](https://youtu.be/2H5uWRjFsGc). More of a joke, but I think most English-speaking people would understand.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany that one will be _very_ age dependent. I'd have understood it, but I was born in 1980. I doubt anyone more than ~5 years older/younger than I would recognize the reference.

Comment: @terdon - how very dare you? I'm nearly a decade and a half older than you and I got it straight away - that record was pervasively catchy, horribly annoying, and utterly ubiquitous; surely no-one who was over five years old at the time it came out can or will ever forget it! :-D

Comment: Heh, fair enough, and my apologies for any offense although none was intended, @Spratty! :) I would still argue that those who were not around at the time are unlikely to remember it, but I stand corrected about my venerable elders :P.

Comment: What is the Arabic for the original expression?

Comment: @terdon I was born early-mid nineties and I recognize it too. But then I do tend to surprise people by making references to things they assume I wouldn't know, like the Pythons or *Porridge*.

Comment: @Prometheus I am not sure what they are referring to but it might be the expression وقت الجد مرّ which translates to something like ''he gets tough when the times get tough, he rolls with the punches and takes them''.

Comment: @Prometheus - بيقع واقف

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You could say that he always **lands on his feet.** [TfD defines this as:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/land+on+feet)

> To end up in a positive or comfortable position after being involved in a bad or difficult situation.

Comment: Which comes from, “Cats always land on their feet.”

Comment: @Davislor A saying that is [very much grounded in reality!](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_righting_reflex)

Answer (score 4):

Another metaphor is **come up smelling of roses**.

> *come up smelling of roses*
>
> to be in a better or stronger situation than before, after
> experiencing a difficult situation
>
> - *Ellis, who was sacked on Monday, has come up smelling of roses. He has been taken on by a rival company and his financial package is even
>   healthier.*

[[Collins Easy Learning Idioms Dictionary.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/come-up-smelling-of-roses)]

Though there is often the implication that someone's threatened reputation comes through intact, there does not need to be.

> - *Whoever is rewarded for taking the risk when push comes to shove in tonight's final round will come up smelling of roses.*

[Times, Sunday Times (2007); via Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/come-up-smelling-of-roses)]

> - *Hearts had struggled to gain any real foothold in the game but, ... [they]  staged another dramatic late show as they rallied.... Hearts
>   entered extra-time with renewed vigour and they were rewarded as the
>   clock ticked down. An almighty rammy in the area, which saw the ball
>   rattle the cross bar, ended with Zaliukas providing the decisive
>   strike.... After a fraught night, it was Hearts who came up smelling
>   of roses.*

[[The Herald; Feb 2012](https://www.heraldscotland.com/sport/13047447.st-johnstone-1-hearts-2-visitors-come-smelling-roses-valentines-night/)]

Comment: Perhaps it's me, but I associate the idea of "coming up smelling of roses" with luck and fortuitous events beyond a person's control. It doesn't strike me as being related to resilience and determination.

Comment: Cambridge has a different take on it: [*to have people believe that you are good and honest after a difficult situation that could have made you seem bad or dishonest:*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-up-out-smelling-of-roses) This is the meaning I am more familiar with too. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20out%2Fup%20smelling%20like%2Fof%20roses) says: *to have success or good fortune in a situation in which one was likely to fail, be harmed, etc.*

Answer (score 2):

From [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/what-doesnt-kill-you-makes-you-stronger/):

> **What doesn’t kill you, makes you stronger**
>
> What doesn’t kill you, makes you stronger comes from an aphorism of
> the 19th century German philosopher Friedrich Nietzsche. It has been
> translated into English and quoted in several variations, but is
> generally used as an affirmation of resilience.

Another idiom is *tough as nails*.
Example : Jamison is tough as nails. She survived a near-fatal car accident and got better after relentless therapy.

You may also see the *Light At The End Of The Tunnel*, meaning that bad days will hopefully end.